# Do solid-state lasers emit hadrons at some exitation state?

Tags: photons, laser

Given an observation at a solid-state emitter at it's current limit where the device creates more photons than the crystal dissipates (reflected and thermally); thus making photons to impact over themselves at a intensity. 
Is it possible the emitter may be producing specifically hadrons, neutrinos, neutrons or other differentiable particles from the wavelength? or may such particles be simply packs of photons which are emitted out of the beam phase by some defective properties at the medium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The photons in a laser do not “impact over themselves” and the laser does not emit anything but photons.

There is a tiny probability that two photons scatter off of each other due to virtual electron-positron pairs in the quantum vacuum, but this is far too small to affect the operation of lasers.

If a laser were able to produce gamma rays, colliding these high-energy photons would have a significant probability of creating real electrons and positrons. But no solid state lasers produce gamma rays. The energy levels of atoms are too small to produce photons whose energy is more than the mass of an electron.